# MVC Controller - getting duplicate querystings without using request.querystring?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

When I use JQuery to serialize a list of id's for my querystring it produces a url like:

```
mydomain/mypage?id=1&id=2&id=3&id=4
```

**Here is what my form looks like**

```
<div><input type="text" name="id" value="1" /></div>
<div><input type="text" name="id" value="2" /></div>
<div><input type="text" name="id" value="3" /></div>
<div><input type="text" name="id" value="4" /></div>
<div><input type="text" name="id" value="5" /></div>

<div><a href="#" id="myLink">CLICK ME!</a></div>
<script>
$('#myLink').click(function() {

//see: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/
myids = $('input[name=id]').serialize();

alert( myids );
return false;

});
</script>
```

-live demo - http://jsfiddle.net/yDpu6/2/

---

When trying to get the querstring values from my controller ActionResult I only get the first id (eg: 1) but when using Request.Quesrtring["id"] I get all the id's (eg:: 1,2,3,4).

Is there a way that I can pass all the serialized id's into my controller without using Request.Quesrtring["id"]?

Comment: please share your view

Answer (score 0):

If you are assuming below code will give all the values, your assumption is wrong

> var value = ('.classname').val();

You need to push the value to array before posting the ids.

**View Code**

```
<input type="text" class="idList" value="1"/>
<input type="text" class="idList" value="2"/>
<input type="button" value="Post Values" onclick="javascript:postValues()" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function postValues() {
    var values = [];
    $('.idList').each(function () {
        values.push($(this).val());
    });

    postData = { id: values }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/PostIds",
        data: postData,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert($('.idList').val());
        },
        traditional: true
    });
}
</script>
```

**Action Method code**

```
public ActionResult PostIds(List<string> id)
{
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You're right, I was sloppy in implementing the JQuery solution. You have done a better job. But I was sloppy primarily b/c the form approach is the better option. The JQ option was included for the sake of exhaustion. Can you really justify why this SHOULD be implemented asynchronously?

Comment: I am not insisting this could be done only asyc, this can also we done with form post. I am giving note saying, If you are doing asyc post back, don't forget to collect all the values into an array before posting the data.

Comment: Would you say this is better handled async?

Comment: yes, without form post. As you know this works well for partial post back (collect the data, build the object and post to controller).

Comment: So you don't interpret the OP's mention of querystring as evidence that a a different View will handle the data render?

Comment: sorry Dave A, I did not get you.

Comment: I was challenging you whether the user's intent was to navigate. The use of querystring indicates that. I'm not challenging you to make an issue as much as to point out the difference between posting facts and trying to help. I like your posts. I think you can improve your posts a lot by paying a little more attention to user's intent.

Comment: yes, I agree with you. Answer deviated from user intent/question.  Just started my adventure in stackoverflow. Some time after posting answer, the question did get edit. That confuses me little,  Thanks for putting me on right track and appreciation @Dave A .